# What happens if I use an access mask with top of pipe bit as stage?

Tags: vulkan

Let's say that I record a transfer command in a command buffer data that needs to be read from the shader. Also assume that a transfer has been made of vertices and indices to the buffers bound. I don't want any drawing operations to begin until the transfers have completed. So I put a global memory barrier:

```
cmd_buffer->placeGlobalMemoryBarrier(
/* src_stage */ VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 
/* dst_stage */ VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, 
/* src_access_mask */ VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT, 
/* dst_access_mask */ VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT);
```

The VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT is supposed to say make all memory visible before reading from the shader. But is this not enough to ensure that the vertices and indices are visible?

Furthermore, let's say I want to read the uniform from BOTH the vertex and fragment shader, the access mask of VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT mask is enough, right? I don't need VK_ACCESS_UNIFORM_READ_BIT, right?

Comment: "*The VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT is supposed to say make all memory visible before reading from the shader.*" All memory visible ***to*** reading from the shader. Access masks about about... how you access it. And the destination access mask says how the destination is going to access it.

Comment: @NicolBolas The destination stage I have top of pipe, and the access flag as VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT, is this sufficient for reading from fragment shader, vertex shader, vertex input, index input?

Comment: Do "vertex input" or "index input" sound like "shader read" operations?

Comment: @NicolBolas They sure do. But the destination access mask won't apply to anything if I put top of pipe, right?

Comment: "*They sure do.*" I'd be curious to know the basis of how those things sound like "shader read" operations. Did you look up what the standard says about that access mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you use an access mask with `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT` is *undefined behavior*. It is not allowed:

> An application **must** not specify an access flag in a synchronization command if it does not include a pipeline stage in the corresponding stage mask that is able to perform accesses of that type.

If you want to cover everything, you need to use `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` instead.

---

`VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT` is not enough to make vertices and indices *visible-to*. This mask only covers the things listed in its descriptions, e.g. per [non-extended Vulkan 1.0 specification](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VkAccessFlagBits):

> `VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT` specifies read access to a *uniform texel buffer*, *sampled image*, *storage buffer*, *physical storage buffer*, *shader binding table*, *storage texel buffer*, or *storage image* in any shader pipeline stage.

`VK_ACCESS_VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE_READ_BIT` and `VK_ACCESS_INDEX_READ_BIT` are for vertex and index buffer, respectively. Both related to the `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT_BIT` stage.

---

<s>`VK_ACCESS_UNIFORM_READ_BIT` is a subset of `VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT`. Either bit covers uniform reads, and can be used with any `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_*_SHADER_BIT` stage.</s>

Nevertheless you hurt nothing by including that access mask bit explicitly.

**Correction**: `VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT` does **not** include `VK_ACCESS_UNIFORM_READ_BIT` per [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs#2169](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/2169).

Comment: What about VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ? So the VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT doesn't include vertex input (index and vertex), how about MEMORY_READ?

Comment: @Zebrafish `VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ` is the hammer. It covers everything that any `VK_STAGE_*` might access.

Comment: @Zebrafish Correction: `VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT` does not include uniform reads.